# How to call loadview Non Statically in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, static, non-static

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf_view', $data)->setPaper('a4', 'portrait');
```

> Non static method 'loadView' should not be called
> statically.intelephense(1036)

Comment: Which "PDF" is it ? Can you share your imports and use statements? Which library

Answer (score 0):

You probably imported the wrong class or you didn't register the facade itself!

If you added the facade in **config/app.php** you need to do this at the top of your controller

```
use PDF;
```

If you want to point to the specific facade class you need to do this

```
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;
```

**PS:** Please share your full code and package name for better understanding.